# Filament PHP access filters form in widgets on dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm new to Filament PHP in Laravel and am using v3. I'm confused about how to access data across widgets that appear in my dashboard. Right now my `Pages/Dashboard` file contains my main dashboard with the filters form, and then i have a series of widgets, starting from my `CustomersChart` that I need to read my filters and generate a query for, how do i do this?

Here's `Dashboard.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages;

use Filament\Forms\Components\DatePicker;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Section;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Forms\Get;
use Filament\Pages\Dashboard as BaseDashboard;

class Dashboard extends BaseDashboard
{
    use BaseDashboard\Concerns\HasFiltersForm;

    public function getColumns(): int | string | array
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public function filtersForm(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Section::make()
                    ->schema([
                        DatePicker::make('startDate')
                            ->maxDate(fn (Get $get) => $get('endDate') ?: now()),
                        DatePicker::make('endDate')
                            ->minDate(fn (Get $get) => $get('startDate') ?: now())
                            ->maxDate(now()),
                    ])
                    ->columns(2),
            ]);
    }
}
```

And I need access to filters in `CustomersChart` and all my other widgets:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Widgets;

use Filament\Widgets\ChartWidget;

class CustomersChart extends ChartWidget
{
    protected static ?string $heading = 'Customers';

    protected static ?int $sort = 3;

    public ?string $filter = 'today';

    protected function getData(): array
    {
        return [
            'datasets' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Blog posts created',
                    'data' => [0, 10, 5, 2, 21, 32, 45, 74, 65, 45, 77, 89],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Blog posts created 2',
                    'data' => [0, 10, 5, 2, 21, 32, 45, 74, 65, 45, 77, 89],
                ],
            ],
            'labels' => ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getType(): string
    {
        return 'line';
    }

    protected function getFilters(): ?array
    {
        return [
            'today' => 'Today',
            'week' => 'Last week',
            'month' => 'Last month',
            'year' => 'This year',
        ];
    }
}
```

Here's the key metrics overview, responsible for the top stats

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Widgets;

use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget as BaseWidget;
use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget\Stat;

class KeyMetricsOverview extends BaseWidget
{
    protected static ?int $sort = 1;

    protected function getColumns(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    protected function getStats(): array
    {
        return [
            Stat::make('Customer churn', '5.45%')
                ->description('57.5%')
                ->descriptionIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up')
                ->color('danger'),
            Stat::make('Avg. customer lifetime', '18.333 months')
                ->description('-36.51%')
                ->descriptionIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up')
                ->color('danger'),

        ];
    }
}
```

[image]